# change setInterval to requestAnimationFrame

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

How do I change the following code? I did not know how to convert this code. Can anyone help me?

```
let timer = ref(30);
let interval = setInterval(() => {
    if (timer.value === 0) {
        clearInterval(interval)
        alert('done')                
    } else {
        timer.value--
    }             
}, 1000)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work the same way as your original code. Of course, you don't need to pass an interval since `requestAnimationFrame` will be timed to the screen refresh rate.

```js
let timer = ref(30);
function mainLoop() {
      if (timer.value === 0) {
        alert('done')                
    } else {
        timer.value--
    }
  requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
}
requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
```

First the function mainLoop is defined. Then, it is called through requestAnimationFrame at the end of the script to 'kickstart' the loop. The subsequent calls to requestAnimationFrame within the function are there to maintain it.

Comment: May you enlighten me, why are there two requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);?

Comment: There's no replacement for clearInterval

Comment: First the function `mainLoop` is defined. Then, it is called through `requestAnimationFrame` at the end of the script to 'kickstart' the loop. The subsequent calls to `requestAnimationFrame` within the function are there to maintain it.